# Cannot lift sails after upgrade to 1.0

Tags: mysql, sails.js

I got this error when upgrading sails to 1.0

**TypeError: Waterline.Model.extend is not a function**

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you verify the upgrade procedures in the official [Upgrading to Sails v1.0](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/upgrading/to-v-1-0) doc?

Comment: your question is very broad, please provide the stack trace of the error and steps you have taken to update your sails. For example, from which version you are upgrading and etc.